# как вывести первое совпадение в bs4 чтобы они не чередовались

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36",
           "Accept-Language": "ru-RU"}

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
movies = soup.find_all('a', class_='ipc-title-link-wrapper')
year = soup.find_all('span', class_='sc-14dd939d-6 kHVqMR cli-title-metadata-item')
rating = soup.find_all('span', class_='ipc-rating-star ipc-rating-star--base ipc-rating-star--imdb ratingGroup--imdb-rating')
i = 1
for m, y, r in zip(movies, year, rating):
    print(f'{m.get_text()}, {y.get_text()} - {r.get_text()}')
    i += 1 ```
````